# If an equation has multiple roots of same value , What does it signify?

Tags: quadratics

$(x-1)^{560}$ is said to have 560 roots. Now , all the roots must be 1(since it is the only factor tha can be formed ). And another example is $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 $ , Here $  x = 1$ ,only root as answer.

Q1 By saying $560$ roots , It does not give an difference to the answer( I mean that there is only root possible ) but does it give a difference  in the graph of the function ?.

Comment: Dod you mean $x^2-2x+1$?

Comment: "Does it give a difference in the graph of the function?" Have you tried graphing a simple example? Like $(x-1)$ versus $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes , i have . A upward parabolic curve which is on the 2 unit of x axis.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question: there's a difference between those two graphs.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy So , there will be a difference just like a curve ?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Aaah. I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of these functions

$$f(x)=(x-1)^{560} \\ g(x)=x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2$$

are not equal.  This means that the graphs are also different.

I accept

$$f(x)=(x-1)^{560}, ~g(x)=(x-1)^2$$

Both functions get equal value at the point $x = 0,1,2.$ This means that the graphs pass through the same point, but it does not mean the graphs are the "same".

Just notice that:

- If $x≠0,1,2$, then $$(x-1)^2≠(x-1)^{560}.$$

This means, graps can never be the "same".

When will the graph of two functions be the same?

Of course, when these functions are equivalent functions.

For example:

$$\color{blue}{f(x)=|x|} \qquad \color{red}{g(x)=\sqrt {x^2}}$$

Since the values ​​of the functions are the same at all points, the graphs are also the same.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Roots of multiplicity become interesting when looking at the structure of a polynomial.

But, if you only care about the graph... if the multiplicity is even, the graph will touch the x-axis but not "cut through" the x-axis.  If it is odd, it will cut through.

The graph will be "flat" in the neighborhood of a root of high multiplicity.

The graph of $y = (x-1)^{560}$ will be very nearly zero for all x in (0,2), and then quickly shoot up toward infinity for any x outside of this range.